# itext PDF 7 Greek Letters appear as empty squares when using Text() inside Paragraph()

Tags: java, fonts, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am having some weird problem with itextpdf 7 which i use to generate on the fly a pdf and send it to the client using a java restful api. 
When i use the following code to generate pdf everything works fine:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(baosPDF);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
document.setMargins(100, 20, 20, 20);

//      LOAD BOOKMAN OLD STYLE FONTS
String REGULAR = "Fonts/BOOKOS.TTF";
String BOLD = "Fonts/BOOKOSB.TTF";
String ITALIC = "Fonts/BOOKOSI.TTF";
String ITALIC_BOLD = "Fonts/BOOKOSBI.TTF";

PdfFont regularFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(REGULAR, "Identity-H", true);
PdfFont boldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(BOLD, "Identity-H", true);
PdfFont italicFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(ITALIC, "Identity-H", true);
PdfFont italicBoldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(ITALIC_BOLD, "Identity-H", true);

Table table = new Table(2);
table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.setFont(regularFont);

// When i use String directly inside paragraph it works
// The Following Works and Greek language is printed OK.

paragraph.add("Αρ. Πρωτ.: " + Integer.toString(incident.getProtocolNo()));
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setPadding(7);

cell.add(paragraph);
table.addCell(cell);

document.add(table);
document.close();
```

However, because i would like to have both **bold** and **normal** text inside a paragraph i tried to use **Text()** inside paragraph but it doesn't work: It prints greek letters as empty squares. My code is:

```
// THE FOLLOWING IS NOT WORKING. IT PRINTS GREEK LETTERS AS EMTPY SQUARES...

text1 = new Text("Ημερομηνία: ");
text1.setFont(boldFont);
text1.setFontSize(11);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = formatter.format(incident.getDate());
text2 = new Text(date);
text2.setFont(regularFont);
text2.setFontSize(11);
paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(text1);
paragraph.add(text2);
cell.add(paragraph);
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

Why don't greek letters appear correct in this situation? What am i doing wrong? Please help...

Comment: In your second code snippet, if you put greek text with `regularFont`, do they appear alright? And that case it seems like your font doesn't support greek characters in bold.

Comment: No it does support, i have tested it already. The same happens to regular font if i use Text() inside Paragraph(). If Greek weren't supported by the fonts (Bookman Old Style) they wouldn't be printed in any case.

Comment: You are putting non-ASCII characters in your code. That's asking for encoding problems. Why don't you use the Unicode notations?

Comment: It is well possible that a character is supported by the normal font, but not by the bold or the italic version of the font. But alas, as you say, that is not the case here.

Comment: Bruno Lowagie i will try it and see. You are right this might cause problems. Obviously you are talking about the colon character. Well i substituted the colon with \u003A but i get exactly the same,

Comment: I was talking about Ημερομηνία which can cause problems on many levels: the encoding that was used to save the file could be wrong (I don't expect this is the case, but I've seen this problem when files were stored in a versioning system that expected a different encoding). The encoding that was used to compile the code could be different (that's the usual suspect). The encoding used when running the program could be different. Those are all things that can go wrong even before iText is involved.

Comment: Of course, if what I say was the culprit, this wouldn't print fine either: Αρ. Πρωτ

Comment: The file encoding is UTF-8. And why when i use greek directly in the Paragraph constructor prints fine, and instead if i use Text() objects added to paragraph nothing gets printed. I think there must be something with Text() and the way they are handled by paragraph maybe??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the font i was using for bold. It didn't contain the greek language while it should. I downloaded it again from a different site and the size was triple compared to the previous one. Now everything works fine.